# How accurate are internal terminators on chips with high speed differential inputs?

Tags: semiconductors, digital-communications, high-speed, tolerance, semiconductor-process-technology

I'm aware that due to process variation, some analog parameters of semiconductor devices can vary; sometimes quite a lot. (E.g. the [SST3904](https://www.rohm.com/products/transistors/bipolar-transistors/automotive-bipolar-transistors/sst3904hzg-product) transistor specifies a DC current gain somewhere between 100 and 300).

In my project I am using the [EZ-USB™ CX3 MIPI CSI2 to USB 5 Gbps Camera Controller](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/universal-serial-bus/usb-peripheral-controllers-for-superspeed/ez-usb-cx3-mipi-csi2-to-usb-5gbps-camera-controller/#) from Cypress (now Infineon). This chip has a MIPI CSI-2 camera input, with [internal 100R termination](https://community.infineon.com/t5/Knowledge-Base-Articles/CX3-Hardware-Frequently-Asked-Questions/ta-p/248990).

Neither the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-CYUSB306X_EZ-USB_TM_CX3_MIPI_CSI-2_to_SuperSpeed_USB_bridge_controller-DataSheet-v17_00-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c7d0d8da4017d0ecbbb354559), nor the [technical reference manual](https://community.infineon.com/gfawx74859/attachments/gfawx74859/usb-superspeed-peripherals/302/1/CX3_TRM.pdf), for the part make any mention of the internal termination, let alone specify its tolerance.

What is likely to be the tolerance for the internal 100R termination?

Comment: How accurate does it need to be? My attitude has always been that it's probably at least as good as the tolerance on the actual impedance of the traces, connectors and cables used in the connection, and that the effects of a slightly mismatched terminator are so minor in terms of overall signal integrity, that it isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: Thee requirement is in the standard, so if the part advertises that it complies with USB 3.1 then the differential impedance at the input to the receiver will be between 72 ohm and 120 ohm. See section 6.8.3 **Receiver Electrical Parameters**. The same goes for MIPI.

Comment: @PeterSmith - I believe it's within spec. What I'm wondering is if in practice we'll see some devices with some values at the bottom end of the spec, and some devices at the top end.

Comment: @DaveTweed - The only reason I'm asking is that, in our system, we're seeing some boards work perfectly, and some producing frame drops. The root of this problem is that probably some part of the transmission line is out of spec. But I want to confirm that variation between boards is more likely to be due to (within spec) variation of the termination resistance, than due to poor soldering for example.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at termination impedances of few chips I've used recently, it is approximately within 20% of the nominal.

However some of the chips indicate in the terninology that there is a range of values, which means these chips can support adjusting the termination, which also means if the user can adjust it, also the chip manufacturers can calibrate the settings and store them inside the chip, while still allowing the used to select one of the factory calibrated settings.

So basically, they are generally thought to be accurate enough to pass any certification testing if such tests are performed to some interface which has a specification for it.

Answer (score -1):

> What is likely to be the tolerance for the internal 100R termination?

Whatever is needed for it to be useful for the function it needs to do. IOW, it is designed to whatever standard governs transmission on the terminated lines. The chip would be a bit useless otherwise.

Comment: I believe that's true, but I was hoping for an actual number, especially as seen in the wild.